# How to justify this complex substitution using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I tried to solve the laplace transform of $\cos(at)$ and $\sin(at)$ using Euler's formula. That is,
$$\int^\infty_0e^{-(s-ia)t}dt\color{red}{=}\frac{1}{s-ia}\int^\infty_0e^{-t}dt=\frac{1}{s-ia}$$
Taking the real and imaginary parts immediately gives $\mathcal{L}\left\{\cos(at)\right\}(s)=\dfrac{s}{s^2+a^2}$ and $\mathcal{L}\left\{\sin(at)\right\}(s)=\dfrac{a}{s^2+a^2}$.

My question is: Is it possible to justify the first equality using contour integration?

Answer (score 0):

You can justify that equality by a substitution. Let $u = (s-ia)t$. Then $du = (s-ia)dt$.
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(s-ia)t}dt = \frac{1}{s-ia}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}du
$$
Since $u$ is a dummy index, we can let $u = t$ so 
$$
\frac{1}{s-ia}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}dt = \frac{1}{s-ia}
$$
If then multiple by $1=\frac{s+ia}{s+ia}$, we have
$$
\frac{s+ia}{s^2+a^2}
$$
and as you say 
\begin{align}
\text{Re}\biggl\{\frac{s+ia}{s^2+a^2}\biggr\}&= \frac{s}{s^2+a^2}\\
\text{Im}\biggl\{\frac{s+ia}{s^2+a^2}\biggr\}&= \frac{a}{s^2+a^2}
\end{align}
We can also take the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s-ia}$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s-ia}ds &=
\lim_{s\to ia}(s-ia)\frac{e^{st}}{s-ia}\\
&= e^{iat}
\end{align}
which is what we took the Laplace transform of to begin with, $\mathcal{L}\{e^{iat}\}$.